# Apache Flink how do I go about mapping & matching an alternate-key with a primary key to one keyed Stream

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like a simpler better and more elegant way of approaching the below problem. I have yet to come across any documentation on the topic , and i am sure there my current approach has some bottle necks , thank you

I have a stream where Json is mapped to a POJO

```
DataStream<MYPOJO> stream = env.
             addSource( <<kafkaSource>>).map(new EventToPOJO());
```

Some of the fields of the POJO will have a populated **primary key** and some will have a populated **alternate-Key** , Some will have both .The only example of working with two keys I have found in Flink document, is using a keyselector for a composite key but nothing for alternate keys

My current approach is as follows :

1. Use a richFlatMapFunction to collect all elements of primary key into stream , **Astream**
2. Use a richFlatMapFunction to collect all elements of alternate Key into a stream , **BStream**
3. USe richFlatMap for items that have both primary and alternate keys, **CStream**
4. Join the Astream with the Cstream on Primary Key
5. Join the Bstream with the Cstream on Alternate Key
6. finally KeyBy Primary Key

```
 DataStream<MyPOJO> primaryKey = stream.flatMap(new RichFlatMapFunction<MyPOJO mypojo, MyPOJO mypojo>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(MyPOJO mypojo, Collector<MyPOJO> collector) throws Exception {
                if(mypojo.PrimaryKey() != null){
                 
                    collector.collect(MyPOJO);
                }
            }
        });


 DataStream<MyPOJO> alternateKey = stream.flatMap(new RichFlatMapFunction<MyPOJO mypojo, MyPOJO mypojo>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(MyPOJO mypojo, Collector<MyPOJO> collector) throws Exception {
                if(mypojo.getAlternateKey() != null){
                 
                    collector.collect(mypojo);
                }
            }
        });


 DataStream<MyPOJO> both = stream.flatMap(new RichFlatMapFunction<MyPOJO mypojo, MyPOJO mypojo>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(MyPOJO mypojo, Collector<MYPOJO> collector) throws Exception {
                if(mypojo.getAlternateKey() != null && mypojo.getPrimaryKey() !=null ){
                 
                    collector.collect(mypojo);
                }
            }
        });



//Join them 

   both.join(alternateKey)
                .where(MyPOJO::getAlternateKey)
                .equalTo(MyPOJO::getAlternateKey)
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(1)))
                .apply (new JoinFunction<MyPOJO, MyPOJO, MyPOJO>(){
                   
                    @Override
                    public StateObject join(MyPOJO Mypojo, MyPOJO mypojo2) throws Exception {

                      // Some Join logic to keep both states 
                        return stateObject2;
                    }
                });

:: repeat for primary key stream ...


// keyby at the end
both.keyBy(MyPOJO::getPrimaryKey)
```

I'm sure I could use a filter function As well to achieve the 3 streams , but I would like not to have to split into 3 streams in the first place, please not I have simplified the above for readability sake so please dont mind any syntax errors you may find.

Comment: What is the logic for two records to be joined? Is it `((primary == primary) OR (alternative == alternative))`? Or is there additional logic when both primary & alternative keys exist?

Comment: right now yes its prime = prime , alternate = alternate , what Id rather have is if not prime = prime then  alternate = alternate

Comment: Some questions : Why are you using RichFlatMap if you can use a simple FilterFunction ? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/FilterFunction.html

And , if you want to manage complex keys, I think that you can use the KeySelector funcions ( https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/functions/KeySelector.html )

Comment: yes a simple filter would be more appropriate, however that doesn't affect the solution - a key selector needs to be deterministic, it will not return the correlated identities

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a custom POJO that contains the primary & secondary keys. It needs to have `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, which implement your required logic(*) of when two records are equal. See
[hashCode() and equals() method for custom classes in flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63677057/hashcode-and-equals-method-for-custom-classes-in-flink) for more details on why you have to do this.

Add a `MyPOJO.getJoiningKey()` that returns this custom POJO.

Then just do a single join based on `.where(r -> r.getJoiningKey()).equals(r -> r.getJoiningKey())`.

(*) I'm still not sure of what you want your logic to be. E.g. if left-side primary & secondary key is not-null, and right-side primary key is null but secondary key is not-null, what would you want to compare?

Comment: So what you saying is,  if I override the hashscode and equals method then I can keyby a composite object.  that's brilliant this might work. I will try it out. Basically i just wanna to group states by the same key or alternate key.  i am using different types of sensors some will return the pk in the event the other can only return a relative  id aka alternate key. the above logic is a simple example , Should I elaborate further ?

Comment: Seems like it's worth a try, at least. Pretty easy to create a unit test to validate.

Comment: Did it work? Adding a follow-up is very helpful for others who might run into this same situation, thanks.

Comment: Hi unfortunately it didnt work as the hashvalue needs to be deterministic and sometimes there wont be a value in there hence the hash won't be the same and will not be the same object, thank you for the suggestion though